# Restarting game/scene from another layer

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I’m having a real headache trying to diagnose this problem for quiet awhile now.

**Details:**
I have the following nodes:

1. GameLayer; the main game layer, also a semi-singleton.
2. HUDLayer; a simple HUD layer (for score and pause button), added to the scene along with GameLayer of course.
3. PauseLayer; a CCLayerColor subclass which holds a simple menu (resume, restart, and main menu).

The PauseLayer is added to the GameLayer as a child whenever the pause button is pressed.

**Problem:**
Restarting the game/scene works fine by: *[self restartGame]* from within GameLayer itself.
But invoking the same method from PauseLayer by using: *[[GameLayer sharedGameLayer] restartGame]* does not completely replace the GameLayer scene with a new instance; old scene is still there with no childs, same old score, etc, albeit GameLayer’s dealloc is being called (Only if no transition is used).

**Code:**

GameLayer

```
static GameLayer *sharedGameLayer;

@implementation GameLayer

- (id)init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
    if(self = [super initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255) width:[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width height:[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height])
    {
        NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

        sharedGameLayer = self;
        .
        .
}


+ (GameLayer *)sharedGameLayer {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedGameLayer == nil) {
            sharedGameLayer = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return sharedGameLayer;
}


- (void)pauseGame
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    if (![[CCDirector sharedDirector] isPaused])
    {        
 // Disable the top menu.
        self.hud.topMenu.enabled = NO;

 // Pause game.
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

 // Pause the background music.
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] pauseBackgroundMusic];

 // Disable touch detection.
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher removeDelegate:self];

 // Add the Pause Layer.
        PauseLayer *pauseLayer = [[PauseLayer alloc] init];
        pauseLayer.tag = 2;
        pauseLayer.zOrder = 10;
        [self addChild:pauseLayer z:10 tag:2];
    }
}


- (void)restartGame
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher removeAllDelegates];
    [self stopAllActions];
    [self unscheduleAllSelectors];
    [self unscheduleUpdate];

    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameLayer scene]];
 //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[GameLayer scene]]];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    sharedGameLayer = nil;
}

@end
```

---

PauseLayer

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super initWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 128) width:[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width height:[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height])
    {
 // Create a menu.

 // Resume button.
        CCLabelTTF *resumeLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Resume" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
        resumeLabel.color = ccc3(240, 240, 240);
        CCMenuItemLabel *resumeButton = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:resumeLabel block:^(id sender) {
            [[GameLayer sharedGameLayer] resumeGame];
        }];

 // Restart Game button.
        CCLabelTTF *restartLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Restart" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
        restartLabel.color = ccc3(240, 240, 240);
        CCMenuItemLabel *restartButton = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:restartLabel block:^(id sender) {
            [[GameLayer sharedGameLayer] restartGame];
        }];

 // Main Menu button.
        CCLabelTTF *mainMenuLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Main Menu" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
        mainMenuLabel.color = ccc3(240, 240, 240);
        CCMenuItemLabel *mainMenuButton = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:mainMenuLabel block:^(id sender) {
            [[GameLayer sharedGameLayer] gotoMainMenu];
        }];


        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:resumeButton, restartButton, mainMenuButton, nil];
        [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:10.0];
        menu.position = ccp([CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width / 2, [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height / 2);
        [self addChild:menu];
    }

    return self;
}
```

EDIT:
If I add the Pause layer (as a child to GameLayer, and always visible) in the GameLayer's init method, everything works perfectly.. which is a bit weird.


Any input is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit of the problem was calling the CCDirector's *ReplaceScene:* method after pausing the game using the CCDirector's *Pause* method.
 What I did was implementing my own "Pause" functionality mainly using: *[self pauseSchedulerAndActions];* and also in my case: *[[self.spidersBatchNode children] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(pauseSchedulerAndActions)];* for all the children inside of the spriteBatchNode.
 Another problem arised for which I'll make another question.
Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: Here's the URL of the new question, just incase anyone wanted to follow up: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395827/properly-restarting-re-initializing-a-semi-singleton)

Answer (score 0):

from the line

```
static GameLayer *sharedGameLayer;
```

You needed to write this line before @implementation class line to make it isn't class member variable. and at sharedGameLayer method you should change it to

```
+ (GameLayer *)sharedGameLayer {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedGameLayer == nil) {
            sharedGameLayer = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return sharedGameLayer;
}
```

And, when you define game layer class you don't call init method but you should call sharedGameLayer to make game layer class be singleton.

Comment: _static GameLayer *sharedGameLayer;_ is indeed already outside of @Implementation directive, I've corrected that in code.  I've also modified the _+ (GameLayer *)sharedGameLayer_ method as you suggested but unfortunately the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: EDIT: If I add the Pause layer (as a child to GameLayer, and always visible) in the GameLayer's init method, everything works perfectly.. which is a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest using singleton pattern on CCLayers, however did you override / edit the CCScene wrapper so it doesn't call init.

For instance

```
+(id)scene
{
    CCScene* scene = [CCScene node];
    [scene addChild:[GameLayer sharedGameLayer]];
    return scene;
}
```

Then when you call

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameLayer scene]];
```

Remember to restart your game right after

```
[[GameLayer sharedInstance] restart];
```

Or you could do that in the scene wrapper method.

Hope I got your point.

Atleast this will save you from reallocating space for the game layer all the time hehe..

Comment: _[scene addChild:[GameLayer sharedGameLayer]];_ gives an Assertion Failure.    Also, the _restart_ method is the one that actually replaces the scene.<br/>Anyway, I've almost solved the problem with some arising issues, so I'll edit my question first.