# Properly restarting/re-initializing a semi-singleton

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using the semi-singleton approach for the main game layer/scene of my cocos2d game as shown in the later code.

**The objective** is to properly restart/recreate this singleton scene using a button in a pause or gameover layers by calling: *[[GameLayer sharedGameLayer] restart]* method.

**The problem** is if I use a CCTransition effect for that, and override the GameLayer's *dealloc* method with *sharedGameLayer = nil;* line (to ensure the resetting of the static variable), the sharedGameLayer variable stays nil after the first restart (aka. after the first dealloc), so calling the *restart* method does nothing.

**What works with suspicion** is not to override the *dealloc* method at all, but before restarting the scene using *replaceScene:*, I set the sharedGameLayer to nil.

**Question:** Is this the right approach for restarting/recreating this semi-singleton class?

Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

GameLayer.m:

```
static GameLayer *sharedGameLayer;

@implementation GameLayer

- (id)init
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
    if (self = [super initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255) width:[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width
                             height:[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height])
    {

        // Set the sharedGameLayer instance to self.
        sharedGameLayer = self;

        // Set the initial game state.
        self.gameState = kGameStateRunning;

        // Register with the notification center in order to pause the game when game resigns the active state.
        NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(pauseGame) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];

        // Enable touches and multi-touch.
        CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
        [director.touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
        director.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;


        // Set the initial score.
        self.score = 5;

        // Create the spiders batch node.
        [self createSpidersBatchNode];

        // Load the game assets.
        [self loadAssets];


        // Play Background music.
        if (![SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].isBackgroundMusicPlaying)
            [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"backgroundmusic.mp3" loop:YES];

        // Preload sound effects.
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"inbucket.mp3"];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"outbucket.mp3"];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"gameover.mp3"];

        // Schdule updates.
        [self scheduleUpdate];
        [self schedule:@selector(releaseSpiders) interval:0.7];
    }

    return self;
}



- (void)createSpidersBatchNode
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    // BatchNode. (For Animation Optimization)
    self.spidersBatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"spiderAtlas.png"];

    // Spider sprite + BatchNode + animation action.
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        Spider *spider = [[Spider alloc] init];
        spider.spiderSprite.visible = NO;
    }

    [self addChild:self.spidersBatchNode];
}



- (void)restartGame
{
    // Play button pressed sound effect.
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button.mp3"];

    // Nil'ing the static variable.
    sharedGameLayer = nil;

    // Restart game.
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[GameLayer scene]]];
}



+ (CCScene *)scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // Game Layer.
     // 'gameLayer' is an autorelease object.
    GameLayer *gameLayer = [GameLayer node];

     // add gameLayer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: gameLayer];

    // HUD Layer.
    HUDLayer *hudLayer = [HUDLayer node];
    [scene addChild:hudLayer];
    gameLayer.hud = hudLayer;

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}



+ (GameLayer *)sharedGameLayer
{
    return sharedGameLayer;
}



- (void)cleanup
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher removeDelegate:self];
    [self stopAllActions];
    [self unscheduleAllSelectors];
    [self unscheduleUpdate];

    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
    self.hud = nil;

    [super cleanup];
}



//- (void)dealloc
//{
//    sharedGameLayer = nil;
//}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet your new game layer is created before the first one deallocates, therefore it sets the static var to nil. Check that sharedGameLayer equals self in dealloc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I stated earlier in my question that after the first restart/dealloc of the GameLayer scene, the **sharedGameLayer** variable is always nil if the `-dealloc` is overridden with `sharedGameLayer = nil;` line. Or do you mean that I should set the variable to self in the `-dealloc` method? That would sound weird as you're setting it to self in the `-init` method in your book.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use dealloc to set the static variable to nil. Dealloc happens *after* your object has stopped being used. Never use it for controlling the behaviour of your app.

For all you know, 30 minutes might have passed between when you set `sharedGameLayer` to `nil` and when the `dealloc` method gets called. Or perhaps `dealloc` will *never be called at all*.

Your code looks good, just delete the commented out "dealloc" code.

Also, this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Should be done in the `-dealloc` method in addition to your custom `-cleanup` method. It is perfectly fine to remove an observer twice, if it's already been removed nothing will happen.

Another note, `+sharedGameLayer` should return a variable of type `instancetype` and it should be responsible for setting the `sharedGameLayer` variable. If you `sharedGameLayer` inside `-init`, you will run into bugs.

For example:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedGameLayer
{
    if (sharedGameLayer)
        return sharedGameLayer;

    sharedGameLayer = [[[self class] alloc] init];

    return sharedGameLayer;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (!(self = [super init]))
        return nil;

    .
    .
    .

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my posted code in the question to include the full **-init** method, and as you can see there's a **-createSpidersBatchNode** method that actually calls a spider class to create spiders in the batchNode which is actually contained in the GameLayer's class itself, so there's a loop happening (**-init** -> **-createSpidersBatchNode** -> **Spider's class** -> **[[GameLayer sharedGameLayer].spidersBatchNode addchild:]** -> **sharedGameLayer** -> **-init-** ..etc). That's because sharedGameLayer is never given a chance to be set to self think.